# SQL Server trigger (access on row)

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I want to create 2 types (INSERT, UPDATE) of trigger in SQL Server:

```
CREATE TRIGGER  [dbo].[trigger_upd_ins] 
ON [dbo].[Kunden] 
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO [updateTab] (rowid, tablename, command) 
    VALUES (rowid, 'Kunden', 'INSUPD')
END
```

DELETE:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[trigger_del] 
ON [dbo].[Kunden]
FOR DELETE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO [updateTab] (rowid, tablename, command) 
    VALUES (rowid, 'Kunden', 'DELETE')
END
GO
```

I want to write the index of the changed row (rowid) in an other table.
But how did i have access to this column?

Greetz Simon

Answer (score 0):

within the trigger you have access to two special tables called inserted and deleted these tables mirror the columns of the table that you attach the trigger to.

you can use these just like real tables ie. you can use them in joins etc.

```
select i.*
from inserted i
```

more info here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/ms191300.aspx